# Possible to make raycast detect only sides of an object?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a sort of "Sound ray-caster" in Unity2d, but I found an issue where once a ray was inside an object, I had no way for it to detect where the end of the object is. The raycast would end immediately if it began inside an object, which is not what I want to happen. Is there a way I can have a raycast only detect the start/end of an object? Any other solutions to my problem is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the raycast direction and continue some distance forward, then have a raycast to the opposite direction. if you hit the same object then you know where the object ends. otherwise increase the distance and try again.

Comment: Wouldn't this be slow with a lot of rays in the world? Also, how do I make sure the ray only collides with one object (in case another one is in the way)?

Comment: Of cause you have to think about how to minimize the amount of raycasts. Perhaps you can have the relevant objects in a separat layer? Also you need a good starting point for the opposite raycast. Perhaps you better start far of and come closer if you hit another object? Or start small because you have a lot of objects? Or you can use  the [Mesh.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html). 
You have to evaluate each hit and check if you hit the same object. If not: just use the position as a new starting point and cast again.

Comment: I suppose I could do that.. There is also the issue that if the object has an empty space in the middle (like a doughnut), the opposite ray would only detect the end of the object rather than the point inside the doughnut. It should be an edge case though, ill try implementing your solution!

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the collider's bounds ? It would work for simple meshes. Or you could have trigger collider on the mesh's ends and only raycast to those ?